# how to distribute items inside recycle-view evenly?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

i Have recycle view as follow:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <!-- items inside below RecycleView require to distribute evenly -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!-- items inside above RecycleView require to distribute evenly -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and below how i set the items of above recycle view:

*I tried to be as much as possible using linear layout (unless you tell me that is not possible)*

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(mBinding.getRoot().getContext(), LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false);
mBinding.myRecycle.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);

myAdapter = new Adapter();
mBinding.myRecycle.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

and below is the item that i like to have it distribute horizontal and evenly

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <data> <variable name="obj" type="com.myapp.test.model.entity.SomeData"/> </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

i read few article that said to put 0dp width and set weight as 1 but,
with that suggestion (above code), i receive a big empty vertical blank space (Text view is not shown), like below:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
| the second recycle view           |
| goes here                         |
+-----------------------------------+
```

if i set width as wrap and remove weight it is shown like this

```
+-----------------------------------+
|tv10|tv20|tv30|tv40|               |
|tv11|tv21|tv31|tv41|               |
+-----------------------------------+
| the second recycle view           |
| goes here                         |
+-----------------------------------+
```

while **what i want is like this**:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|  tv10  |  tv20  |  tv30  |  tv40  |
|  tv11  |  tv21  |  tv31  |  tv41  |
+-----------------------------------+
| the second recycle view           |
| goes here                         |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: what do u want exactly ??

Comment: I want to distribute items in my recycleview evenly - see my last diagram

Comment: Check the posted answer if you are still looking for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this layout manager in place of linear layout manager, it will work for sure. This layout manager makes sure all items are evenly distributed like you need them to. https://gist.github.com/saurabhdhillon/d982627cb9296d0a2d00f1d664bdb8ac

Credits: https://gist.github.com/heinrichreimer

Comment: At least give valid credits to the repo from where you have copied the code -> https://gist.github.com/heinrichreimer/39f9d2f9023a184d96f8/revisions

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**

try this.You should make 'LinearLayout' as root view of your item layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, however, your answer will make TV10 and TV11 within 1 item distribute evenly (refer to my diagram in question).
while i like to have TV10 and TV11 in the vertical orientation (top-bottom) but, within items TV1x, TV2x, TV3x and TV4x they are evenly distributed (horizontal)

Comment: @AnD Sorry, I got your problem now, Try my updated answer, just make your linear layout as root view

Comment: Let me try your updated answer, just curious, is the xmlns:android attr necessary?

Comment: @AnD yes it should be in root view as it provides access to predefined attributes in Android SDK

Comment: I received duplicate attr, because I already have: `<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >` as my root element.  see my xml in question

Comment: I told you to remove that line, make LinearLayout as your root

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put this in question (I thought it's not relevant) , I have data binding in the xml, which not allowing me to remove <Layout> - I updated my question, you can see my updated XML